# Integral with $\delta$ function

Tags: integration, distribution-theory, dirac-delta, quantum-field-theory

I got this integral in a quantum field theory problem:

$$
\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\!\!\! dp \, 
\frac{p^2 \delta\left(\sqrt{p^2-m_2^2}+\sqrt{p^2-m_3^2} -m_1\right)}{\sqrt{p^2-m_2^2} \sqrt{p^2-m_2^3}} 
$$

Are there any 'tricks' to compute  integrals  where there $\delta$ is composed with another function?

EDIT: The solution is $\frac{\sqrt{(m_1-m_2-m_3) (m_1+m_2-m_3) (m_1-m_2+m_3) (m_1+m_2+m_3)}}{m_1^2}$. I calculated it as proposed in the answers.

Comment: what about changing variables?

Comment: Please check if the differential I added is ok.

Comment: I tried $u=\sqrt{p^2-m_2^2}+\sqrt{p^2-m_3^2} -m_1$, but it gets very messy. I'd like to know if there is a better way to deal with this kind of integrals.

Comment: Provided $f$ is continuously differentiable and it has most countably many simple roots $r_n$, $\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x) \delta(f(x))=\sum_n \frac{g(r_n)}{|f'(r_n)|}$. This can be heuristically proven by changing variables. This is entirely applicable to your situation, since $\sqrt{p^2-m_2^2}+\sqrt{p^2-m_3^2}-m_1$ is a nice increasing function of $p$, so there is a single root. Assuming it does not occur at $p=m_2$ or $p=m_3$, everything will be OK.

Comment: That might be helpful

Comment: Incidentally, are $m_1,m_2,m_3$ all positive here?

Comment: Yes, there are particle masses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that:

- $f$ has at most countably many roots $r_n$
- $f$ is continuously differentiable at $r_n$ for each $n$
- $f'(r_n) \neq 0$ for each $n$.
- $g$ is continuous, at least at $r_n$.

Then

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x) \delta(f(x)) dx=\sum_n \frac{g(r_n)}{|f'(r_n)|}$$

One can heuristically prove this using a change of variable, but as a strict mathematical matter this should be considered to be a definition.

In your case, $f(p)=\sqrt{p^2-m_2^2}+\sqrt{p^2-m_3^2}-m_1$. This function is increasing for $p \ge \max \{ |m_2|,|m_3| \}$, decreasing for $p \le -\max \{ |m_2|,|m_3| \}$, and not real-valued elsewhere. It is also even. So for fixed $m_2,m_3$ and sufficiently large $m_1$, $f$ has two roots, both of which satisfy the assumptions above.

Comment: By the way, does that formula generalize for roots of multiplicity greater than one?

Comment: @mlainz No. Actually, unless $g=0$ at such a root, the resulting expression will not even be defined.

Answer (score 1):

We have (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Composition_with_a_function))
$$
\delta\left(\sqrt{p^2-m_2^2}+\sqrt{p^2-m_3^2} -m_1\right) 
= \delta(g(p)) 
= \sum_k \frac{\delta(p-p_k)}{\lvert g'(p_k)\rvert}
$$
where
$$
g(p) = \sqrt{p^2-m_2^2}+\sqrt{p^2-m_3^2} -m_1
$$
which has simple roots at $p_k$:
$$
g(p_k) = 0
$$